# Erratic behavior in Windows?

Tags: windows, go, mingw

```
  Update:  The question title can be misleading.  This was not Go's fault at all.
           See the first comment or the accepted answer.
```

This following code (well, almost the same) counts page views under Linux allright, but counts them double under Windows.

Can someone figure out why?

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
    "http"
)

func main() {
    println("Running")
    http.HandleFunc("/", makeHomeHandler())
 http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

// this version compiles and run OK under the Linux version of Golang
func makeHomeHandler() func(c *http.Conn, r *http.Request) {
    views := 1
    return func(c *http.Conn, r *http.Request) {
     fmt.Fprintf(c, "Counting %s, %d so far.", r.URL.Path[1:], views)
        views++
    }
}

/*
// this version compiles and run OK under the mingw version of Golang
// it uses a different argument type for the handler function,
// but the counter says "1 so far", then "3 so far", "5 so far", and so on.
func makeHomeHandler() func(c http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    views := 1
    return func(c http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     fmt.Fprintf(c, "Counting %s, %d so far.", r.URL.Path[1:], views)
        views++
    }
}
*/
```

Under Mingw:

```
http://localhost:8080/monkeys => Counting monkeys, 1 so far.
http://localhost:8080/monkeys => Counting monkeys, 3 so far.
http://localhost:8080/donkeys => Counting donkeys, 5 so far.
```

Could this be a bug?

Followup:

In fact, if I define an additional handler for another page, like:

```
   http.HandleFunc("/test", testPageHandler)
```

Wich does not have a closure, nor increments anything, the counter gets incremented anyway, but only +1:

So, still under Mingw:

```
http://localhost:8080/monkeys => Counting monkeys, 1 so far.
http://localhost:8080/monkeys => Counting monkeys, 3 so far.
http://localhost:8080/test   => Another handler function that does not increment "views"
http://localhost:8080/donkeys => Counting donkeys, 6 so far.
```

Under Linux output is as spected:

```
http://localhost:8080/monkeys => Counting monkeys, 1 so far.
http://localhost:8080/monkeys => Counting monkeys, 2 so far.
http://localhost:8080/test   => Another handler function that does not increment "views"
http://localhost:8080/donkeys => Counting donkeys, 3 so far.
```

Comment: Solved!  It's not Go's fault.
My Windows based browsers keeps asking for favicon.ico along with every request.  Thanks @distributed !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the behaviour you're seeing is due to the browser requesting a favicon for your page and not due to Windows/mingw. In case you wonder, I'm using 6g ond Darwin, my Firefox 3.6 is also running on Mac OS X.

To underline my suspicion, try adding the following to the handler function:

```
fmt.Printf("Counting %s, %d so far.\n", r.URL.Path[1:], views)
```

Then you can see all the requests reaching your application. One request from a freshly started Firefox to the URL http://localhost:8080/chuchichaestli yields this output:

```
Counting chuchichaestli, 1 so far.
Counting favicon.ico, 2 so far.
```

because Firefox also requests the favicon for your go page.

Furthermore you're not locking/synchronising access to `views` even though there could be multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: How can I lock access to `views`?

Comment: As mentioned, this code is **unsafe** as it has a data race on reading/writing to the counter. The correct approach is to use something like [`n := atomic.AddInt64(&views, 1)`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt64https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt64) or [`expvar`](https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/). There are no [benign/safe data races](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong).